# Error occur in angular like Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'

Tags: angular

I'm fresher angular developer i have following specification that require for angular cli
 - Angular CLI: 7.0.7 Node: 10.13.0 OS: win32 x64 Angular: 7.0.4
*But there is 1 error occur .error is*

> ERROR in src/app/products/products.component.ts(28,12): error TS2322:
>   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.   Property 'length'
>   is missing in type '{}'.

***product.component.ts***

```
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoryService } from './../category.service';
import { ProductService } from './../product.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent {
  products: Product[] = [];
  filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
  categories$;
  category: string;

  constructor(
    route: ActivatedRoute,
    productService: ProductService,
    categoryService: CategoryService
  ) {
    productService
      .getAll()
      .switchMap(products => {
        this.products = products;
        return route.queryParamMap;
      })

      .subscribe(params => {
        this.category = params.get('category');

        this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ?
          this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category) :
          this.products;
      });

    this.categories$ = categoryService.getAll();
  }
}
```

> *Error occur on following line  .switchMap(products => {
>              this.products = products;    // Error occure on this line
>             return route.queryParamMap;*

Answer (score 1):

the right way would be to add typing to your service like this

```
class ProductService {
  getAll() {
    this.http.get<Product[]>(...);
  }
}
```

this will cast your response type to `Observable<Product[]>` and error will disappear

Comment: This is the correct solution, check has to be done as you get the object, not forced elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change

```
.switchMap(products => {
...
}
```

to

```
.switchMap((products: Product[]) => {
...
}
```